# Why does my dice throwing program get stuck?

Tags: java, arrays, random

My program is supposed to roll a pair of dice 1000 times in an array, then spit out the frequency of each number at the end. I thought I did this right, but it keeps getting stuck on the ++ when running. What's wrong, and how can I fix it?

```
import java.util.Random;
public class dice {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] counter = new int[12];
        for (int i = 0 ; i<1000; i++)
        {
            int roll1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            int roll2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            int sum = roll1 + roll2; 
            counter[sum]++;
        }
        System.out.println("***********Results************");
        for (int j=0; j<13; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(j+"  occured  "+counter[j]+" times");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indexing of your array goes out of bounds. In Java, arrays indexing is zero-based. You are getting 12 maximum, which is one position to high:

```
rand(6) + 1 // either: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
rand(6) + 1 // either: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

So the sum of both will be one of these: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12. But you can only index from 0 until 11 inclusive, if you create an array of 12 elements. Note that there are only 11 possible sums.

Answer (score 0):

During the while loop, If ever your sum gets a value of 12 (Happens when Both dice rolls to 6)
With the way you access the count[] Array, the valid index range is from 0-11.So in this case you get the exception. Here is a simple fix to this and a code that works.

```
public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] counter = new int[13];
        int roll1,roll2,sum;
        for (int i = 0 ; i<1000; i++){
            roll1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            roll2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            sum = roll1 + roll2; 
            counter[sum]++;
        }
        System.out.println("***********Results************");
        for (int j=1; j<13; j++){
            System.out.println(j+"  occured  "+counter[j]+" times");
        }
    }
}
```